# Java Generics cannot convert Type in Type

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble with this:

```
public class Test {

    static class TestType {}

    static class Pair<A,B>{}

    public static void main( String [] args ) throws Exception {

        Collection<? extends TestType> val = null;

        List<? extends TestType> single = 
            testSingle( val ); // OK

        Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>> pair = 
            testPair( val ); // ERROR

    }

    static <T extends TestType> List<T> testSingle( Collection<T> val ){
        return null;
    }

    static <T extends TestType> Pair<String,List<T>> testPair( Collection<T> val ){
        return null;
    }

}
```

Why is the first one working and the second one isn't?

The Error message ist:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Test.Pair<String,List<capture#3-of ? extends Test.TestType>> to Test.Pair<String,List<? extends Test.TestType>>
```

EDIT:

using Braj's Answer I setup this to clearify the Problem when not using generic type T:

```
public class Test {

    static class TestType {}
    static class Implementation extends TestType {}

    static class Pair<A,B>{}

    public static void main( String [] args ) throws Exception {

        Collection<Implementation> val = null;

        List<Implementation> sinle = testSingle( val ); // OK

        Pair<String,List<Implementation>> pair = testPair( val ); // OK
        Pair<String,List<Implementation>> pair2 = testPair2( val ); // ERROR
        Pair<String,List<Implementation>> pair3 = testPair3( val ); // ERROR
        Pair<String,? extends List<Implementation>> pair4 = testPair4( val ); // ERROR

        run( val );

    }

    private static void run( Collection<? extends TestType> val ){

        List<? extends TestType> single = testSingle( val ); // OK

        Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>> pair = testPair( val ); // ERROR
        Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>> pair2 = testPair2( val ); // ERROR
        Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>> pair3 = testPair3( val ); // OK
        Pair<String,? extends List<? extends TestType>> pair4 = testPair4( val ); // OK
        Pair<String,? extends List<? extends TestType>> pairX = testPair( val ); // OK
        //My-Name-Is
        @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
        Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>> fixed = 
            (Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>>)
            (Pair<String,?>) testPair( val ); // OK but ugly and stupid(?)
    }

    private static <T extends TestType> List<T> testSingle( Collection<T> val ){
        return null;
    }

    private static <T extends TestType> Pair<String,List<T>> testPair( Collection<T> val ){
        return null;
    }

    // Braj1
    private static <T extends TestType> Pair<String, List<TestType>> testPair2(Collection<T> val) {
        return null;
    }

    // Braj2
    private static <T extends TestType> Pair<String, List<? extends TestType>> testPair3(Collection<T> val) {
        return null;
    }

    // Seelenvirtuose
    private static <T extends TestType> Pair<String, ? extends List<? extends TestType>> testPair4(Collection<T> val) {
        return null;
    }

    // This one works in the way I wanted.
    private static <T extends TestType> void runOK( Collection<T> val ){

        List<T> single = testSingle( val ); // OK

        Pair<String,List<T>> pair = testPair( val ); // OK
    }
}
```

EDIT2: I can fix this in run() using:

```
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>> fixed = 
    (Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>>)
    (Pair<String,?>) testPair( val );
```

But this is rather ugly and stupid (?).

EDIT3: I edited the above to include Seelenviruose's answer and it's still getting weirder.

**I still don't know why this is needed...**

EDIT4: Finally got it working without ugly casts: if I use `<T extends TestType> run(...)` the compiler doesn't complain. I changed it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the first one working and the second one isn't?

Because `List<ASpecificSubTypeOfTestType>` (the return of the first method) is a subtype of `List<? extends TestType>`, but `Pair<String, List<ASpecificSubTypeOfTestType>>` (the return of the second method) is not a subtype of `Pair<String, List<? extends TestType>>`.

Let us change your example from `Pair` to `List`, and `TestType` to `Object` for a moment:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main( String [] args ) throws Exception {

        Collection<?> val = null;

        List<?> single = testSingle( val ); // OK

        List<List<?>> pair = testList( val ); // ERROR

    }

    static <T> List<T> testSingle( Collection<T> val ){
        return null;
    }

    static <T> List<List<T>> testList( Collection<T> val ){
        return null;
    }

}
```

From a technical point of view, `List<SomeSpecificType>` is a subtype of `List<?>`, but `List<List<SomeSpecificType>>` is not a subtype of `List<List<?>>`, for the same reason that `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>` -- the type parameters are different concrete types (one is `List<SomeSpecificType>` and the other is `List<?>`).

For a more practical reasoning, `testList` returns a `List<List<T>>` for some `T`. We don't know what that `T` is, but we know that it is *some concrete type*. And this `List<List<T>>` that is returned is a list that can only contain `List<T>`. It cannot contain `List<S>` if S is not T, because `List<S>` and `List<T>` are not subtypes of each other. Even though we don't know what T is, we know that there exists some choice of T, and all the element lists must have that T as the type parameter.

On the other hand, the type you're assigning it to, `List<List<?>>`, is a list that can contain every type of list at the same time. So you can put in a `List<Integer>` and a `List<String>`, etc. at the same time and it would be okay. You can never do that with a `List<List<T>>`, no matter what you choose `T` to be.

Therefore, the two types are clearly incompatible.

What can go wrong? With the `List<List<?>>` reference, you can insert `List<Integer>` and `List<String>` into the list. And then with the `List<List<T>>` reference inside the function, you can extract all the elements as `List<T>`, which they won't be. So it is unsafe.

You might say, what if I never put things into the `List<List<?>>` reference? Is that safe? But if that were the case, you should instead use `List<? extends List<?>>`. The `? extends` wildcard makes it a consumer, so you cannot insert anything into it except `null`; and it also makes the type compatible (`List<List<SomeSpecificType>>` is a subtype of `List<? extends List<?>>`).

The moral of the story is, wildcards in deeper parameters do not mean what you think they do.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the long answer. I'll try to think it through. (As I try for Seelenvirtuoses' answer who is trying to tell me the same thing I think). I would give an additional +1 for the last sentence, though :)

Comment: Since you seem to have a deeper understanding of this subject could you do me a favor and comment on my own "Solution" where I'm wrong (even if it solved the problem?)

Comment: Thanks again. I think I (almost) undertstand it now. :) I

Answer (score 3):

The return type of your second method *call* is

```
Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>>
```

Why is that the return type? Well, the compiler infers that type from the input argument *val* that is of type `Collection<? extends TestType>`.

The upper bounded wildcards are the Java mechanism to break generic's inherent invariance. With such a construct the following is possible:

```
Collection<? extends Number> c1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
Collection<? extends Number> c2 = new HashSet<Double>();
```

Note, that I introduced two kinds of polymorphism. One for the collection type, and another for the type variable.

Without the upper bounded wildcard the following construct is be a compiler error:

```
Collection<Number> c3 = new LinkedList<Integer>(); // compiler error
```

Why the error? Simple: If you have a `Collection<Number>` you would expect to being able to add a `Double` object into it. But this would not be allowed into a `LinkedList<Integer>`. Hence, error.

The downside of this upper bounded wildcard is now, that you can't add anything (except `null`) into a `Collection<? extends Number>`.

---

*Cut: If you understood it until now, the rest should be easy.*

---

You now introduced an additional layer into the generic return type. You do not return a list of something, you return a pair of a string and *some list*.

So the upper bound now must not be on the type `T` of your list elements. It must be placed onto the list itself!

With the following method declaration

```
<T extends TestType> Pair<String, ? extends List<T>> testPair(Collection<T> val) { ... }
```

the following call will be allowed:

```
Pair<String, ? extends List<? extends TestType>> pair = testPair(val);
```

But ... I doubt that anything reasonable is possible with such a pair. If so, you must reconsider your design.

Comment: So you're saying that `Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>>` can't be assigned to a variable of type `Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>>`? I find nested generic types confusing sometimes, but even this seems rather odd...

Comment: I confess even so I did unterstand the part until the cut I still don't get the later part. As a Sidenode: If I understand your first part correctly you *can* add something to a List<? extends Number>:     static <T extends Number> void add( List<T> list, T value ){ list.add( value ); }

Comment: Not to forget: Thanks for the long explanation!. About "doing something usefull": In the real application the method testPair is something like: void <T extends Article> Pair<Errors,List<T>> filter( Collection<T> articles ){ List<T> result = new List<>(); Errors ers = new Errors(); Error e; for( T t : articles ) if( ( e=t.check() ).ok() ) result.add( item ); else errors.add( e ); return new Pair( ers, result ); } ... which (at least) I regard as very usefull ;) (The real method is a little longer but it returns to me a filtered list of articles and an explanation for the missing ones.)

Comment: I included your answer in my question's test-code. And it's getting even weirder. As you can see in the first case it prodces an error and in the second case it works.

Comment: @Scheintod The problem is not with the type `TestType`. It is with the type `List`. The compiler does not know, which _subtype_ of a `List` is actually part of the pair. So you can't assign it to a `Pair<String, List>`. It must be a `Pair<String, ? extends List>`. (Man, I maybe could explain it better in German ... :-) )

Comment: And I could ask better in German ;) anyway. Perhaps I would understand it if you could tell me why `Pair<String,List<Implementation>> pair = testPair( val );` is OK while `Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>> pair = testPair( val );` is not. (and what it has to do with `List`)

Comment: Oh. And I just found out that this is working without changing testPair: `Pair<String,? extends List<? extends TestType>> pairX = testPair( val );`

Comment: Ui! _Caution: You changed the type of variable `val` from `Collection<? extends TestType>` to `Collection<Implementation>` in your various examples._ This causes the compiler to infer another type to the type parameter _T_. With your first declaration even the line `Pair<String,List<Implementation>> pair = testPair(val)` does not compile!

Comment: I know that generics are a bit complicated. The best advice I can give is to look at the wildcard `?` as being a _subtype_ mechanism.

Comment: @does not comile: Yes it does. Just checked with the code from above. Meanwhile I got one step further and found compiling code which does what I want it to do without ugly casting. I think the real problem has nothing to do with the List but with different types of ? as explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html (which I must confess I don't understand completely, yet)

Comment: "The return type of your second method call is Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>>" No it isn't. The return type of your second method call is `Pair<String,List<SomeTypeHere>>`. We don't know what type goes in there (it is the same type that the wildcard in `val` represented), but it's a pair whose second item is a specific type of list. However, it is very different from `Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>>`, which is a pair that can accept *any type of list* as the second item, and this pair object you can dynamically change the second item from one type of list to another type of list.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
private static <T extends TestType> Pair<String, List<TestType>> testPair(Collection<T> val) {...}

Pair<String, List<TestType>> pair =  testPair(val);
```

OR

```
private static <T extends TestType> Pair<String, List<? extends TestType>> testPair(Collection<T> val) {...}

Pair<String, List<? extends TestType>> pair =  testPair(val);
```

Comment: Both kinda "work" in this case with returning null. But in both cases I loose the information that the provided Type is the same as the returned one. Which is the whole Point of this kind of methods.

Comment: On the other Hand if I use class Implementation extends TestType and call Pair<String,List<Implementation>> = testPair( ... ) it works. But I can't use it this way in another geneneric Method ...

Answer (score 0):

I read through the answers and they explain why it doesn't work but I didn't notice any offers for how to solve it. I solved it in my situation by making the method a generic method.

```
public main(){    
  Map<String, List<Integer>> stuff = service.buildStuff();
  consumeStuff(stuff);
}

private <T extends Number> consumeStuff(Map<String, List<T>> stuff){
  ...
}
```

So the method consumeStuff() expects the 2nd type of the map to be a List which has a type of something that extends Number (so Integer or Double). By having a map (the var stuff inside main()) with the explicit type of Integer for the List means that Java can infer the type when calling the generic method consumeStuff().

Inside consumeStuff we can treat the contents of the inner list as a number. We can dig into it, grab a value from the list and pass it to a method/constructor that accepts type Number.

Answer (score -1):

Meanwhile I found this page about Wildcard-Capture: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

As I understand it the problem is that the compile generates different types

- for the local variable: `Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>>`
- and the return value: `Pair<String,List<capture#3-of ? extends TestType>>`.

The "fix" for this Problem while keeping the original method signature is to parametrize the calling method with `<T extends TestType>`. For the example it looks like this:

```
public class Test {

    static class TestType {}

    static class Pair<A,B>{}

    public static <T extends TestType> void main( String [] args ) throws Exception {

        Collection<T> val = null;

        List<T> single = testSingle( val ); // OK

        Pair<String,List<T>> pair = testPair( val ); // OK

    }

    static <T extends TestType> List<T> testSingle( Collection<T> val ){
        return null;
    }

    static <T extends TestType> Pair<String,List<T>> testPair( Collection<T> val ){
        return null;
    }

}
```

*(this is my first time to write main like this :)*

This *forces* the compiler to use the exacly same type for the variable and the method's return type.

I still feel that the generics are somehow 'buggy' and unpredictable in this regard.

Comment: This changes the problem. While `List<T>` (a list of some specific type) and `List<? extends TestType>` (a list of some unknown specific type) are similar, `Pair<String,List<T>>` and `Pair<String,List<? extends TestType>>` are very different beasts. The former is a pair whose second item can be a specific type of list that is fixed, while the latter is a pair whose second item you can put in a list of any type, and change it from one type of list to another type of list at runtime, at will. Of course this new problem is easy to solve, but it is not your original problem.